Allow X-frame options for Google Apps Script through Firebase.json
Within Google Apps Script documentation on X-Frame-Options, there are only 2 options, to either use default or allow all. I have no problem adding that setting within my Google Apps Script project, inside my doGet() function, but it seems the options are very limited.
Instead, is there a way we can leave the X-Frame-Options value on DEFAULT, embed the Apps Script as an i-frame into a Firebase project, and modify our firebae.json file to ALLOW this iframe to be visible?
If this is possible, I'm assuming I would need to modify my "Content-Security-Policy" area within my firebase.json file.
This is what I have tried so far, but no luck yet...
    {
      "source": "**",
      "headers": [{
        "key": "Content-Security-Policy",
        "value": "default-src 'self' https://*.googleapis.com https://*.google.com; script-src 'self'; 
      }]
    },


At the end of the day, I don't want any site to iframe my apps script projects...just my sites.

Unless you want to support outdated browsers like IE11 and older, you only need to set Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors directive, as all modern browsers will ignore X-Frame-Options if this is set.
In your Content Security Policy you'll need to add the frame-ancestors directive, probably similar to how you've now configured default-src. frame-ancestors doesn't fall back to default-src as it isn't a fetch directive and thus needs to be set separately.
